# Using Arduino LoRa with RFM9X chipset: How to connect the RMF9x NSS pin?

Tags: lora, arduino

As I am searching on libraries that can be used with Lora and arduino I came across on this one: https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa

Also the RFM9x has the following pinout:
[image: RMF 9x Pinout]

The data transfer on this chip is achieved via an SPI Interface. Also as I see with the librarie's API specification is that I can setup the pins Slave Select (ss), reset and dio0 with the function:

```
LoRa.setPins(ss, reset, dio0);
```

So I should configure the pins reset and dio0 like that:

```
Parameter Name -> On RMF9x Chip pin
reset -> RESET
dio0 -> DIO0
```

But I cannot figure out how to connect the `ss` pin mentioned in the method above, is the on-rmf9x chip the ***NSS*** pin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the library's documentation states the RFM9x's `NSS` pin should get connected into pin `10`. Also as you can see in the following image:

[image: Arduino SPI Interface] the pin 10 is the SPI's slave select pin (`ss` in short) so the `NSS` pin on the RFM9x is connected into slave select pin.

So in the function:

```
LoRa.setPins(ss, reset, dio0);
```

The `ss` variable takes the number of pin that is conected to RFM9x's `NSS` pin.

Furthermore it is obvious that the RFM9x's `NSS` pin is used for **SPI**'s **slave select**.

Comment: Simple clarification: the "N" in "NSS" stands for Negative, i.e., it's an active-low Slave Select. Similar to the NRESET pin of the sx1276, which indicates that reset is active low, unlike what the (incorrect) marking on the module may lead to believe...